# Vm and Ubuntu on mac

Tags: vmware, mac, disk-image

I have a problem with the very start of setting up ubuntu with a VM on mac

Result Code:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component:
SessionMachine
Interface:
ISession {c0447716-ff5a-4795-b57a-ecd5fffa18a4}

This is after I try to add a DiskImage.
I allowed it all on mac in security and privacy
Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Try this?  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689672/virtualbox-ns-error-failure-0x80004005-macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689672/virtualbox-ns-error-failure-0x80004005-macos)

Comment: "*try to add a DiskImage?*" Your question should explain that clearly